# Showing that $x^p - a$ either splits or is irreducible for characteristic $p$ (prime) in a field F.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $f (x) = x^p- a \in F[x]$.
Show that $f (x)$ is irreducible over $F$ or $f (x)$ splits in $F$.

If I assume that $f(x)$ doesn't split, then $f(x)$ cannot be written as a product of linear factors.  But I can't find any way to progress towards showing that $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ where one of them is a unit.

Assuming it's reducible and showing that it splits:

If I let $f(x) = p(x)q(x)$ where neither $p(x)$ or $q(x)$ are units, I know I need to show that $f(x)$ can be written as a product of only linear factors, but I can't see how I would show this either.

Comment: What's meant by a non-prime characteristic?

Comment: The characteristic $n$ is not a prime number.

Comment: It is **necessarily** either $\;n=0\;$ or $\;n\;$ a prime, otherwise you seem to be missing a rather basic feature in fields theory. It can **not** not be a prime *unless* it is zero.

Comment: Right.  But the characteristic of a field is either $0$ or prime.

Comment: I miss-read the question and will edit this one.

Comment: @OliverG Check carefully the conditions: with $\;n=0,\,p=3,\,a=2\,,\,\,F=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\;$ you get a counter example.

Comment: Also, make up your mind about whether $\;p,\,n\;$ or something else is the characteristic, and what's its relation to the polynomial's degree. I'd advice to re-write the whole thing again.

Comment: I've re-written the question and changed all the $n$'s to $p$'s.

Answer (score 4):

Let $L/F$ be a field extension which contains a root of $X^p-a,$ call it $\xi \in L.$

Since char$(F)=p$ we have char$(L)=p$ and so $(X-\xi)^p=X^p-\xi^p=X^p-a$ in $L[X].$

So if $X^p-a$ is reducible in $F[X]$, we must have that $(X-\xi)^r \in F[X]$ for some $1\leq r < p.$

$\Big[$*Proof:* Suppose that $X^p-a=g(X)h(X)$ where $g,h \in F[X]$ are both non-constant.

Since $F\subseteq L$, we can view this equation in $L[X].$ In which case, we have

$$(X-\xi)^p=g(X)h(X).$$

By uniqueness of factorization in $L[X],$ it follows that

$$g(X)=(X-\xi)^r \text{ and } h(X)=(X-\xi)^{p-r} \text{ for some } 1\leq r <p.$$

Since $g(X) \in F[X],$ it thus follows that $(X-\xi)^r \in F[X].$ $\Big]$

Expanding out, we get $X^r-r\xi X^{r-1}+\ldots+(-\xi)^r \in F[X].$

In particular, $r\xi \in F$ and as $r\neq 0$ in $F$ (because $1\leq r <p$), we conclude that $\xi \in F.$

Hence $X^p-a$ splits completely in $F[X]$ as $(X-\xi)^p.$

This proves your claim :)

**Appendix**

Let $K$ be any field of characteristic $p.$

*Claim:* For any $x,y \in K,$ we have $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p.$

*Proof:* Follows from binomial expansion and the fact that $\binom{p}{r}$ is divisible by $p$ for all $1\leq r <p.$

Comment: How did you get $(X-\xi)^p=X^p-\xi^p=X^p-a$?  Particularly the $X^p - a$ part?

Comment: Just added an appendix :) For the $X^p-a$ part, this is because $\xi$ is a root of $X^p-a$ and so $\xi^p=a.$

Comment: Are you happy with the proof now? :)

Comment: I don't understand the third line of what you wrote, why does it being reducible imply it's of that form?

Comment: I've editted my answer to address your question. Any good?

Comment: By uniqueness of factorization in $L[X],$ it follows that 

$$g(X)=(X-\xi)^r \text{ and } h(X)=(X-\xi)^{p-r} \text{ for some } 1\leq r <p.$$

How does this follow from the uniqueness of factorization?  Why would $r$ be bound below by $1$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:The Frobenius is an automorphism, so there exists $u\in F, u^p=a, (X-u)^p=X^p-a$.

Comment: I haven't come across the term Frobenius, is there a way to prove this without referencing that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism        For a finite field it is an automorphism.